# Print last line when it matches with previous

Tags: shell, unix, printing, line

I have a file content like

srinivas,100

srinivas,200

srinivas,300

srinivas,400

srinivas,500

madhu,111

madhu,222

madhu,333

madhu,444

vijay,123

vijay,234

vijay,345

vijay,456

vijay,567

vijay,678

I want output like this:

srinivas,500

madhu,444

vijay,678

Comment: You should probably use JSON and/or JQuery

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What language are you working in?  What algorithm are you using to turn your input to output?  Can you show us the code that you have written so far to solve this?

Comment: i need it using unix commands. I am trying with awk

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, you can do it as:

```
awk -F',' '($0 && p != $1 && line){print line} $0{line=$0; p=$1} END{print line}' filename
```

`($0 && p != $1 && line){print line}` checks if current line is not empty, matches the first field (name field) with `p` (initially empty) and checks if `line` variable is not empty or null. If all the condition passes, it will print the variable line.

`$0{line=$0; p=$1}` will update the value of `line` and `p` if line is not null or empty.

The output would be:

```
srinivas,500
madhu,444
vijay,678
```

If you want extra new line, add new-line character in `($0 && p != $1 && line){print line "\n"}`